# How do I put a button in a block in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Used expanded, container. Does not work. I tried to put the Elevated Button in Expanded. And all the time that child can't use something else. Most likely, I don't quite understand the structure. I tried to put the Elevated Button in Expanded.

[image]

```
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Pomodoro(),
  ));
}

class Pomodoro extends StatefulWidget {
  const Pomodoro({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Pomodoro> createState() => _PomodoroState();
}

class _PomodoroState extends State<Pomodoro> {
  double percent = 0;
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names, unused_field
  static int TimeInMinut = 25;
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  int TimeInSec = TimeInMinut = 60;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Color(0xff1542bf), Color(0xff51a8ff)],
                begin: FractionalOffset(0.5, 1)),
          ),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Pomodoro Clock',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                    child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                      percent: percent,
                      animation: true,
                      animateFromLastPercent: true,
                      radius: 90.0,
                      lineWidth: 20.0,
                      progressColor: Colors.white,
                      center: Text(
                        '$TimeInMinut',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 163, 48, 48),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0)),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 30.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              children: const [
                                Text(
                                  'Study Time',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 30.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10.0,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '25',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 80.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              children: const [
                                Text(
                                  'Pause Timer',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 30.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '5',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 80.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                    child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'hello',
                                  ),
                                ))
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'start studing',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use `Expanded` on Text(`hello`) widget. You need to get constrains from top level/parent widget, but this is not the solution you like to archive.

- I will recommend checking [/layout/constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)

As for the answer, you need to wrap `Row` widget `Column` to place another child just after the row widget. It could be skipped if you we had same color as background.

```dart
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Pomodoro(),
  ));
}

class Pomodoro extends StatefulWidget {
  const Pomodoro({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Pomodoro> createState() => _PomodoroState();
}

class _PomodoroState extends State<Pomodoro> {
  double percent = 0;
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names, unused_field
  static int TimeInMinut = 25;
  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  int TimeInSec = TimeInMinut = 60;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Color(0xff1542bf), Color(0xff51a8ff)],
                begin: FractionalOffset(0.5, 1)),
          ),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Pomodoro Clock',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 40.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                    width: 50.0,
                    child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                      percent: percent,
                      animation: true,
                      animateFromLastPercent: true,
                      radius: 90.0,
                      lineWidth: 20.0,
                      progressColor: Colors.white,
                      center: Text(
                        '$TimeInMinut',
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 30.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 163, 48, 48),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0)),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                children: const [
                                  Text(
                                    'Study Time',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 30.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 10.0,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    '25',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 80.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: const [
                                Text(
                                  'Pause Timer',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 30.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '5',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 80.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'hello',
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 100,
                          width: 200,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'start studing',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```